# Include <p> tag after endforeach statement

Tags: php

So I want to be able to include a `<p></p>` using html tags at the end of my foreach statement below, but I keep running into problems with the code.

**Image**:
[image]

**Code**:

```
    <?php if(!empty($mediaUrls)):
        if(is_front_page() || is_home()):
            $counter = 0;
            foreach($mediaUrls as $entry):
                $counter++;
                $mediaurl = $entry['media_url'];
                $permalink = $entry['permalink'];

                if($counter > 6) {
                    break;
                }
                ?>
                <article class="tw-status">
                    <div class="tw-content">
                        <a href="<?= $permalink; ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="" class="insta_image" src="<?= $mediaurl; ?>" width="100%"/></a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            <?php endforeach;
            endif;
        else:
            echo 'No posts available.';
        endif;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close `PHP` first and then you can add `P` tag as below:

```
  <?php if(!empty($mediaUrls)):
        if(is_front_page() || is_home()):
            $counter = 0;
            foreach($mediaUrls as $entry):
                $counter++;
                $mediaurl = $entry['media_url'];
                $permalink = $entry['permalink'];

                if($counter > 6) {
                    break;
                }
                ?>
                <article class="tw-status">
                    <div class="tw-content">
                        <a href="<?= $permalink; ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="" class="insta_image" src="<?= $mediaurl; ?>" width="100%"/></a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <p></p>
            <?php
            endif;
        else:
            echo 'No posts available.';
        endif;
    ?>
```

Hope it helps you.